# Why should these algorigthms behave any differently?

Tags: swift, algorithm, reduce

For personal edification, I'm fiddling around with Swift's `.reduce()` and I've run into an unusual behavior which I can't understand.

I spent quite a lot of unexpected time (at least 6 hours) researching and experimenting, and I'm stumped.

I have two algorithms (I wrote the second one.) which appear to do the exact same thing, which is to count the number of characters (in this case "a") which appear in an infinite string with a repeating pattern. Both algorithms behave the same about 50% of the time. One uses .reduce() twice, and the other -- the working one -- uses a for-loop.

The algorithm which works in all cases is:

```
let str = readLine()!
let length = Int(readLine()!)!

let fullRepetitions = length / str.characters.count
let lengthLastRep = length % str.characters.count

var count = fullRepetitions * str.characters.reduce(0) { $1 == "a" ? $0 + 1 : $0 }

for i in 0..<lengthLastRep {
    if str[str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: i)] == "a" {
        count += 1
    }
}

print(count)
```

And the one which doesn't, **but should**, is:

```
let pattern = readLine()!
let length = Int(readLine()!)!
let fullyRepeatedPatterns = length / pattern.count
let lastPatternLength = pattern.count % length
var countOfAs = fullyRepeatedPatterns * pattern.reduce(0, { $1 == "a" ? $0 + 1 : $0 })
countOfAs += pattern
    .prefix(upTo: pattern.index(pattern.startIndex, offsetBy: lastPatternLength - 1))
    .reduce(0, { $1 == "a" ? $0 + 1 : $0 })
print(countOfAs)
```

On the surface, at least, they appear like they should do exactly the same. But they don't.

At first, I thought I found my problem when performing modulo to get the length of the last pattern, ***yet, if I change the 2nd algorithm to be like the first, it not only stops performing on edge cases but has a serious run-time error.*** Which is to say that changing this:

```
let lastPatternLength = pattern.count % length
```

To this:

```
let lastPatternLength = length % pattern.count
```

Causes the second algorithm with more .reduce() to break (run-time error), ***so I don't think modulo is causing the error.***

More interestingly, the errors are not consistent. An input with:

```
aab
882787
```

Which is "aab" repeated 882787 times, and it looks like an off-by-one error... Or **what appears to be off-by-one**. However...

```
let pattern = "aab"
let length = 882787

let fullyRepeatedPatterns = length / pattern.count
let lastPatternLength = pattern.count % length
var countOfAs = fullyRepeatedPatterns * pattern.reduce(0, { $1 == "a" ? $0 + 1 : $0 })
countOfAs += pattern
    .prefix(upTo: pattern.index(pattern.startIndex, offsetBy: lastPatternLength - 1))
    .reduce(0, { $1 == "a" ? $0 + 1 : $0 })
print("expected 588525 but got \(countOfAs)")
```

I know the correct answer ahead of time, so I can say:

> I expected 588525 but got 588526.

But when inputing:

```
babbaabbabaababaaabbbbbbbababbbabbbababaabbbbaaaaabbaababaaabaabbabababaabaabbbababaabbabbbababbaabb
860622337747
```

It's off by 27!

Finally, ***as if to be very annoying on purpose***, an input of:

```
ababa
3
```

Is off by -1.

There are many cases in which both algorithms work, like:

```
aba
10
```

But I don't care about those.

Can someone please explain what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First:

```
let lastPatternLength = pattern.count % length
```

should be

```
let lastPatternLength = length % pattern.count
```

as in the original algorithm. For example:

```
pattern = "abab"
length = 11

length / pattern.count = 11 / 4 = 2
length % pattern.count = 11 % 4 = 3
```

meaning that two copies of the pattern, plus three additional characters are needed to get a total length of 11.

That this sometimes  caused a runtime error in your tests is due to the second error: In

```
.prefix(upTo: pattern.index(pattern.startIndex, offsetBy: lastPatternLength - 1))
```

you must not subtract one from `lastPatternLength`, it should be

```
.prefix(upTo: pattern.index(pattern.startIndex, offsetBy: lastPatternLength))
```

because `prefix(upTo:)` returns a subsequence up to but *not including* the given index. You can also simplify it to

```
.prefix(lastPatternLength)
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. Though I tried each of your suggestions, I had not tried them together. The old joke about unit testing but not integration testing comes to mind...